# Kohana 3.3 catch-all route

Tags: php, kohana, routes

How can I define a route that will catch all requests and forward them to one specific controller? I've already tried adding the default route

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
         'directory' => 'site',
         'controller' => 'foobar',
         'action' => 'foobar',
));
```

or

```
Route::set('default', '(.*)')
    -> defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'site',
        'controller' => 'foobar',
        'action' => 'foobar',
));
```

to my **bootstrap.php**, but it doesn't work. After typing localhost/a I get either

```
Unable to find a route to match the URI: a
```

or

```
The requested URL a was not found on this server.
```

error. I'm sure that the controller is valid, as

```
Route::set('foobar', 'foo') 
    -> defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'site',
        'controller' => 'foobar',
        'action' => 'foobar',
));
```

works fine.

I'm using Kohana 3.3.

Comment: why would you do that? that would beat the purpose of kohana's MVC

Comment: I'm trying to create a site-building service and I want to store all non-admin sites in a database and load them when needed. The sites are going to be added dynamically (I can't hard code the routes); I don't want them to be available only by localhost/index.php?id=7, but rather via localhost/siteName. The controller will basically do the same things for every site - load titles, meta tags, content etc. The admin sites, however, are normally routed, but I need something to access normal documents.

Comment: I hope my answer helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
Route::set('foobar', '<catcher>',array('catcher'=>'.*')) 
    -> defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'site',
        'controller' => 'foobar',
        'action' => 'foobar',
));
```

It `<catcher>` is a placeholder and `array('catcher'=>'.*')` defines the catcher to match the regex `.*`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, than you very much!

Comment: Leaving the third parameter as NULL will still match everything and skip some of the regex processing. To get the route that was caught use `Request::current()->param('catcher');`